# Android - Cannot find Application class after activating proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

After activating proguard for my android aplication in android studio, the app crashes with error says cannot find `Mypackage.Application` class.

MyApplication classs extends `MultiDexApplication`.

[Here](http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/jY3bffEEgV/Screen%20Shot%201394-12-24%20at%2012.05.01%20PM.png) is the error I got and below is my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar(javax/**)
-keepattributes *Annotation*,InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod,Signature

-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
   @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-dontwarn com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry.**
```

and here is `MyAplication` class:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
private static Context mContext;

public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(mContext);
  }
}
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
--keepresourcefiles AndroidManifest.xml
```

this is default by proguard but you can give a try.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Unknown option '-keepresourcefiles' in line 34 of file '/Users/Amir/AndroidStudioProjects/jarchiapp/app/proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: Can you post your Multidex application class here?

Comment: I posted MyAplication class, take a look